# Selenium/driver's page_source element don't update after clicking a button

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am working on a project where I need to use Selenium to scrape a webpage. Everything goes smoothly until I click a button using Selenium's execute_script command. It executes the command and it seems to work but the driver doesn't update the page_source. I tried everything I waited for the page to fully load and all. I can't seem to find a solution and would be glad if somebody helps out

I have this code that, in the for loop it should open the charging station information one by one, however, the page_source is stuck to the HTML source code of the Cookies Page.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import requests


# Configure a Selenium driver to run the webpage for dynamic actions
# then load the page and perform the actions that needs to be done to
# reach the page to be scraped
driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\Program Files\ChromeDriver\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('https://zes.net/en/charging-stations')
button1 = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'CybotCookiebotDialogBodyLevelButtonLevelOptinAllowAll')
driver.execute_script('arguments[0].click()', button1)
buttons2 = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'item')



# Wait for the page to load and the cookies dialog to disappear
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'item')))

# Load the page that will get scraped
page_to_scrape = driver.page_source

# Load the page that will get scraped
soup = BeautifulSoup(page_to_scrape,"html.parser")


hour_and_type_elements = []

# Create variables to store the certain parts of the HTML elements
num = len(buttons2)
num_v2 = 1793-num
num_v2 += 28
station_names = soup.findAll("div",attrs={"class":"title d-fs-20 m-fs-14 lh-16 fw-500"})
for button_num in range(28,45): #for button_num in range(28,len(buttons2)):
    if buttons2 and num_v2 < len(buttons2):
        button_to_click = buttons2[num_v2]
        try:
            driver.execute_script('arguments[0].click()', button_to_click)
            wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
            wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'detail')))
        except:
            print(num_v2)
    else:
        print("Button not found or index out of range")
        print(num_v2)

    num -= 1
    num_v2 = 1793-num
    num_v2 += 28


    hour_and_type_element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[contains(div[@class='title'], 'Usage Hours')]/div[@class='text']")
    hour_and_type_text = hour_and_type_element.text
    hour_and_type_elements.append(hour_and_type_text)

    station_hours = hour_and_type_elements[0]


# Put these variables into a JSON object and turn it to a file
for station,hours,usage,charging,address in zip(station_names,station_hours,station_usage_type,station_charging_type,station_address):
    print(station.text)
```